# Appwrite Login Auth: TypeError: account.createEmailSession is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, appwrite

I follow this tutorial with Vue, Appwrite
https://appwrite.io/docs/tutorials/vue/step-1

`src/appwrite/index.js`

```
import { Client, Databases, Account } from "appwrite";

const client = new Client();
client
  .setEndpoint("https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1")
  .setProject("PROJECT-ID"); // Replace with your project ID

export const account = new Account(client);
export const databases = new Databases(client);
```

`src/store/user.js`

```
import { ID } from 'appwrite';
import { account } from "@/appwrite";
import { reactive } from "vue";

export const user = reactive({
  current: null,
  async init() {
    try {
      this.current = await account.get();
    } catch (e) {
      this.current = null;
    }
  },
  async register(email, password) {
    await account.create(ID.unique(), email, password);
    await this.login(email, password);
  },
  async login(email, password) {
    await account.createEmailSession(email, password);
    window.location.href = "/";
  },
  async logout() {
    await account.deleteSession("current");
    this.current = null;
  },
});
```

`src/pages/auth/Login.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { user } from "@/store/users";
import { ref } from "vue";

const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
</script>

<template>
  <section>
    <h1>Login or register</h1>
    <form>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" v-model="email" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" v-model="password" />
      <div>
        <button type="button" @click="user.login(email, password)">
          Login
        </button>
        <button type="button" @click="user.register(email, password)">
          Register
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</template>
```

Register function is OK. New user is created in Appwrite Console/Auth.
But when clicking to Login button, it throws an error
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: account.createEmailSession is not a function`

I cannot find a proper answer anywhere.
Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm following the tutorial now as well, but I'm using Vite and React instead. This error was solved on my end by using `createEmailPasswordSession()` instead. Not sure if that would work for a Vue app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).